# Is clicking Edit a vote for Close?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, vote-to-close

I was doing a review for Close Votes on SO, and clicked Edit because there were some issues with the tags. When I finished fixing the tags, I was immediately directed to the next review of Close Votes, and my review count is increased by 1.

Did I just vote Yes (Close) or No on this post?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Editing a post in the Close Votes queue automatically completes review for that question with an implicit Leave Open result (as in the question was not closed) and aging of the existing close votes will begin on that question.

As per this line in the instructions:

> - **Edit** if this question could be improved so that it does not need to be closed

It is assumed that by editing the post, you are improving it the point where it no longer needs to be closed.

Comment: There should be an option to vote to close, but to edit it to make it suck less.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that doesn't make any sense

Comment: @someDoge: makes perfect sense to me. Sure, I'd _like_ the question to be closed, and possibly deleted, since it sucks. But in the meantime, I might like to edit it to remove "Thanks", or clean up formatting, so that it will, as I said, "suck less".

Comment: I could see wanting to tidy up a question you're voting to close as a duplicate, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort in any other cases.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist oh in a duplicate case, sure, of course that makes sense good point. Other cases not so much

Comment: @JohnSaunders Open the actual link in a new tab, review the post, and then make the edit in the new tab.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: that's what I do now. I'm suggesting that this could be made easier to do.

Comment: So, for clarification, is this also the case for the duplicate close reason?  I often clean up dupes since I know they're sticking around but I always assumed it didn't count as a close/reopen vote (woops?)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Wanting to explicitly choose to edit but still vote to close makes perfect sense, but anyone who can see why it makes sense (which is evidently not everybody) will realise that they can open the post in a new tab, and anyone who *can't* see why it makes sense would be deeply confused by having two edit options available. That seems like a good reason for not adding a new option.

Comment: I could also see editing a question that you think should be migrated to another site. You don't want the other site to get poorly formatted questions, do you?

Comment: I agree with John on this one. In particular if the question both need improved formatting and additional input from the OP to become a good question. In such case, I would suggest editing to improve formatting, adding a comment about what information is missing, and finally voting to close. That is probably the best which can be done to teach the OP how to write a good question.